# Django Custom Manager (get Boss' subordinates)

Tags: python, django

I have two models.

Boss:

```
class Boss(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

and Employee:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    boss = models.ForeignKey(Boss, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

I want to create a custom manager that will get Boss' employees, it might be working like this:

```
b1 = Boss.objects.first() 
b1.subordinates.all()
```

I do not know how to implement this actually. I understand I can do something like this:

```
class SubordinatesManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset:
        return super().get_queryset().filter(boss=b1)
```

but this will work only for Employee class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically already have that, you can query like:

```
my_boss.employee_set.all()
```

You might want to change the name `employee_set` by changing the `related_name` attribute of the `ForeignKey`:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    boss = models.ForeignKey(Boss, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subordinates')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
```

in which case the query is thus:

```
my_boss.subordinates.all()
```

You can also perform extra filtering, annotations, etc., like for example:

```
my_boss.subordinates.filter(name__contains='John')
```

to get all `Employees` with `my_boss` as boss, that have `John` in their name.

Comment: that's brilliant. Thank you